# Still no changes in google colab : selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
import time
import sys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver=webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=options)
driver.get("https://rentry.co/wftw8/edit")
driver.implicitly_wait(20)

#print (driver.page_source)
try:

    # here I selected the **span** element that I talk above
    span = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="text"]/div/div[5]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[5]/pre/span')
    # change the innerText thwough js
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].innerText="Hello boy"', span)
    # just wait for the id_edit_code to be present
    edit = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "id_edit_code")))
    edit.send_keys("iRfiNq6M")
    # and same as you had it
    #driver.find_element_by_id("submitButton").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    #driver.find_element_by_link_text("Save").click()
    driver.find_element_by_id("submitButton").click()

except:
     print("Oops!", sys.exc_info()[0], "occurred.")
finally:
    driver.close() 
    print("done")
```

There is no exception but still updating of the text is not reflecting in the url?

Even though there is timer which is enough for the whole code to get processed.
Then also there is no updation.

Currently the text is **Hello** if u visit the URL but I want it to be **Hello boy** using  selenium  , which is done by the below code line:

```
    span = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="text"]/div/div[5]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[5]/pre/span')
    # change the innerText thwough js
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].innerText="Hello boy"', span)
```

But no updation!!?

Comment: the page source needs to be added as well, it may well be an issue with the existing code on the page, reflecting changes, not selenium per se

Comment: What do u mean? Can you write properly or may be show it.

Comment: I mean add the page source code to the question, it may well be an issue with the page code itself and not with selenium driver

Comment: I'm kinda confused u mean the url which I already fetched or adding.. give me an example or something

Comment: `There is no exception but still updating of the text is not reflecting in the url?` can provide what you are expecting and what you are getting?

Comment: If u'll check the url : https://rentry.co/wftw8/edit        the text **Hello** and I want the text to be replaced as **Hello boy** using this code line : ```span = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="text"]/div/div[5]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[5]/pre/span')
    # change the innerText thwough js
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].innerText="Hello cool"', span)```

Comment: @Cal'si : If you do it manually as well will not change the url as you are expecting. Did you try manually?

Comment: It will update the text in URL if I do it manually.

Comment: @Cal'si, most probably that url update is by history API which a headless browser you use might not support

Comment: Then how can I do it?